# Decorator Pattern design

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

I'm pretty new with patterns and I'm studying Decorator Pattern for a program I have to write.

Studying online, I found an example of a Decorator Pattern (it is Java pseudo-code):

```
class Solution1
{
    static interface Component 
    { 
        void doStuff(); 
    }

    static class MyComponent implements Component 
    {
        public void doStuff()
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    static class ComponentDecorator implements Component  // This is the Decorator pattern.
    { 
        private final Component component;

        public ComponentDecorator(Component component) 
        {
            this.component = component;
        }

        public void doStuff()
        {
            this.component.doStuff();
        }
    }

    static class ComponentDecorator1 extends ComponentDecorator 
    {
        public ComponentDecorator1(Component component) 
        {
            super(component);
        }

        private void doExtraStuff1()
        {
            // ...
        }

        public void doStuff()
        {
            super.doStuff();
            doExtraStuff1();
        }
    }

    static class ComponentDecorator2 extends ComponentDecorator 
    {
        public ComponentDecorator2(Component component) 
        {
            super(component);
        }

        private void doExtraStuff2()
        {
            // ...
        }

        public void doStuff()
        {
            super.doStuff();
            doExtraStuff2();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyComponent         c   = new MyComponent();
        ComponentDecorator1 cd1 = new ComponentDecorator1(c);
        ComponentDecorator2 cd2 = new ComponentDecorator2(cd1);

        cd2.doStuff(); // Executes Component.doStuff, ComponentDecorator1.doExtraStuff1, ComponentDecorator2.doExtraStuff2
    }
};
```

When I analyzed the example, I realized that in the past I made a very similar pattern but in different way:

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution2
{
    static interface Component 
    { 
        void doStuff(); 
    }

    static class MyComponent implements Component 
    {
        public void doStuff()
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    static class ComponentDecorator implements Component  // This is NOT the Decorator pattern!
    { 
        private final List<Component> components = new ArrayList<Component>();

        public ComponentDecorator() 
        {
        }

        public ComponentDecorator addComponent(Component component)
        {
            this.components.add(component);
            return this;
        }

        public void removeComponent(Component component) // Can Decorator do this?
        {
            // ...
        }

        public void doStuff()
        {
            for(Component c : this.components) c.doStuff();
        }
    }

    static class ComponentDecorator1 implements Component 
    {
        public ComponentDecorator1() 
        {
        }

        private void doExtraStuff1()
        {
            // ...
        }

        public void doStuff()
        {
            doExtraStuff1();
        }
    }

    static class ComponentDecorator2 implements Component 
    {
        public ComponentDecorator2() 
        {
        }

        private void doExtraStuff2()
        {
            // ...
        }

        public void doStuff()
        {
            doExtraStuff2();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ComponentDecorator cd  = new ComponentDecorator();
        cd.addComponent(new MyComponent());
        cd.addComponent(new ComponentDecorator1());
        cd.addComponent(new ComponentDecorator2());

        cd.doStuff(); // Executes MyComponent.doStuff, ComponentDecorator1.doExtraStuff1, ComponentDecorator2.doExtraStuff2
    }
}
```

In my opinion, the second example can be used in same situations where a Decorator Pattern can be used, but it's more flexible (you may, by example, remove or reorder the components in the list), so my questions:

- Is solution 1 (correct Decorator Pattern) better than solution 2? Why?
- Is it possible to add functions for removing instances in solution 1?
- Is it possible to add functions for reordering instances in solution 1?

Comment: it is impossible to tell which is better because they do different things.

Comment: It seems to me that they do the same thing. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Decorator is about extending another implementation by **wrapping** it in the extending code.
Your solution just calls different implementations sequentially.
Here's [my answer on decorator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379848/decorator-design-pattern-vs-inheritance/12379948#12379948). 
Try to implement that with the alterative approach you describe and you will see the difference

Comment: Do not paste code in comments plz.

Comment: @Zdeslav Vojkovic: It should be as follow: `Stream encryptedZipped = new DecoratorStream().add(new Stream()).add(new EncryptedStream()).add(new ZippedStream())`

Comment: Assuming that basic `Stream` writes to file, how will this write encrypted and zipped data to the file instead of raw data when you call `encryptedZipped.write(data)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 2 is actually a mix between decorator pattern and composite pattern.

I think that solution 1 is better than solution 2 if what you want is just to add behaviour and using solution 1 + composite pattern is better if you also need to use multiple objects as one.

As a more general answer about using this two patterns see
[Difference between the Composite Pattern and Decorator Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233952/difference-between-the-composite-pattern-and-decorator-pattern)

**This is the key answer:**

The composite pattern allows you to build a hierarchical structure (such as a tree of elements) in a way that allows your external code to view the entire structure as a single entity. So the interface to a leaf entity is exactly the same as the entity for a compound entity. So the essence is that all elements in your composite structure have the same interface even though some are leaf nodes and others are entire structures. User interfaces often use this approach to allow easy composability.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

The decorator pattern allows an entity to completely contain another entity so that using the decorator looks identical to the contained entity. This allows the decorator to modify the behaviour and/or content of whatever it is encapsulating without changing the outward appearance of the entity. For example, you might use a decorator to add logging output on the usage of the contained element without changing any behaviour of the contained element.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score 1):

> Is solution 1 (correct Decorator Pattern) better than solution 2? Why?

Solution 1 is better than Solution 2. Solution 1 follows Gang of 4 design as it is.

Solution 1 is

1. Simple
2. Less error-prone compared to solution 2. You have to populate list & clear the list after use (which you are not doing currently). If you are using same decorator in multiple threads, you have to guard your code for memory consistency.

Real world example of *VendingMachineDecorator* is available at this documentation @

[When to Use the Decorator Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549743/when-to-use-the-decorator-pattern/37504043#37504043)

> Is it possible to add functions for removing instances in solution 1?

Yes. It's possible. You to add remove function in abstract Decorator and concrete Decorators.

```
public void removeStuff()
```

You can have a look into below SE questions:

[How to remove decorated object from Decorator Pattern in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239784/how-to-remove-decorated-object-from-decorator-pattern-in-java)

[Can you remove a decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166632/can-you-remove-a-decorator)

Comment: The examples for removing a decorator are really good. On the other side, "Solution 1 is better than Solution 2. Solution 1 follows Gang of 4 design as it is." is not answer. I know solution 1 is better, I'm asking why it is better. Can you provide an answer for question 1?