# Add an Override after the object is created

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm using MVC in my project.

I want to separate the creation of the object from the Override.

How can I do it?

```
table = new JTable() {
        @Override
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
            Component component = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
            int rendererWidth = component.getPreferredSize().width;
            TableColumn tableColumn = getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
            tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(
                    Math.max(rendererWidth + getIntercellSpacing().width, tableColumn.getPreferredWidth()));
            return component;
        }
    };
```

Comment: You may look into Decorator pattern, which allows adding/changing the functionality dynamically to existing objects.  See: [Decorator Pattern Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521842/decorator-pattern-design)

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? @Override has no overhead; it's just there to give a compiler error if the specified method isn't overriding a superclass method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a class which will extend `JTable` and override the method.
2. Create the instance like this:

   ```
   JTable table = new ClassWhichExtendsJTable();
   ```